# Convert x,y to lat, long values

Tags: shapefile, latitude-longitude

I am a senior with limited GIS experience.  I am using QGIS to convert northings and eastings to latitude and longitude. I am having difficulty extracting lat, longs from one last survey shapefile.  I have tried a few different solutions but none worked.

The shapefile loads and displays OK. Here is the process I used for 100+ shapefiles.

```
Run QGIS
Add a new layer
Vector - Geometry Tools - Extract Vertices
Open the layer’s attribute table 
Toggle editing
Open Field Calculator
Create new field – lat      Decimal number (real)   Length 10   Precision 7 Geometry $Y
Create new field – long Decimal number (real)   Length 10   Precision 7 Geometry $X
```

An example of the lat, long values calculated for this particular file 6171174.000000 -6515052.000000

Obviously, this shapefile is different than all the others.

I have seen the ESPG format in previous files. The contents of the prj file are
PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: While we're quite likely to bend over backward to help someone who demonstrates a good-faith effort to complete the task, a request to do the work for you is not likely to garner much in the way of assistance. You should probably [Edit] this Question to document the most promising of your attempts, describing the error or problem encountered.

Comment: Does the shapefile load into QGIS and seem to be in the right place? If it does, then you should be able to transform it to lat-long and get the coordinates out. You've not really described your process or where your difficulty with this shapefile occurs - if you do that we might be able to help.

Comment: "6171174, -6515052" is clearly not a "lat, long" value. Please [edit] the Question to report the coordinate system in the '.prj' file.

Comment: Map data in shapefiles can be in different coordinate systems, and this one is probably one of the systems where its in metres north and east of some point. Check the layer information to confirm this - it will have either an "epsg code" number, or a long text with all sort of parameters in it. To convert to a shapefile with lat-long degrees, use "Layer" menu "Save As..." and find EPSG 4326 in the CRS drop-down. Load into QGIS and it should be in sensible degree numbers...